# On which episodes the Royal Wedding Castle Playset is based?

Tags: my-little-pony-fim, my-little-pony

I got from an exclusive source that my daughter will get the [Royal Wedding Castle Playset](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00859GJWQ) from Santa this year.

[image: Royal Wedding Castle Playset]

She watch the french translation of the show, which is a season late compared to the English version. Which episode should I show her in order to maximize her joy when she will unpack it? I would like to show her the episode where this wedding occurs, and any episode that the story tie in with.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [season 2 finale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Canterlot_Wedding) is what you should show her.  It is a 2 parter, so watch the last 2 episodes in the season.  They're self-contained, introducing new friends (the princess bride and groom that your box cover advertises) and villains.

If you're a season behind the US, I would expect that Season 2 is currently airing.  You should check your local listings to see when *A Canterlot Wedding, parts 1 & 2* air, as those are the episodes.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for Season 2, episodes 25 & 26: [A Canterlot Wedding pt 1 & 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Canterlot_Wedding). Originally aired on April 21, 2012 in the US, they made up the two-part season finale.

Comment: Any building up to those 2 episode, or they could be consumed alone?

Comment: As I understand it, they can be watched out of order from the rest of the series. I am, however, not usually paying much attention to the show so there may have been continuity references that I didn't pick up on.